# Cannot make compass work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, compass-sass

I'm using compass-rails gem in my Rails app. I'm using rails 3.2 and trying to deploy on Heroku cedar stack.

Assets precompilation seemed to pass without any problems.

I keep getting the following error (in the log) when trying to access the site:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently, Heroku must have the following configuration set:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

I added it and everything works fine now.